# Find 5 digits, which have the most numbers of prime numbers

Tags: mathematics, computer-puzzle

If we have to use all available digits once, We can form 9 prime numbers from (2,5,6,7,8), they are :

(25867,28657,56827,65287,65827,82567,82657,85627,86257)

With the same rule, find another **5 digits**, which have the most numbers of prime numbers. Then list all the prime numbers.

Comment: Why is this number theory when this is purely a programming task? Unless there is some dark magic that allows someone to figure out if a number is prime given such conditions, which I sincerely doubt.

Comment: What's wrong with a programming task? Some of us programmers are bored and need something interesting to do... :)

Comment: @greenturtle3141 : Ok I have deleted the number theory tag.

Comment: @wildBillMunson I just don't see the puzzle. Here's a puzzle: How many pairs of cousin primes are there under 1,000,000?

Comment: I mean, y'all been complainin' and murderin questions and sayin they be no "AHA!" moment. Where be the "AHA!" here, then? I too can totally post programmin questions, that ain't got nothin on Project Euler 100+ stuff. But here tho? We just be taking every possible combo of 5 digits, and seeing if by mashin them we get the most possible number of primes. It's all a game of Where's the Biggest Waldo with numbers, except we tell a computer to do it. And I don't even think this is the first game of Hide n'Program Seek on PSE. Lo siento, but I got opinions and I don't believe this is a puzzle.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Thanks for your bonus question! Just wrote up a program and putting Python to work. Just to be clear, do both numbers need to be under 1 million or just the first one??

Comment: Firstly, we gotta stay on topic. Secondly, why do you ask?

Comment: @wildBillMunson It doesn't matter, 1,000,001 is not prime and neither is 999,999

Comment: There are 8,143 pairs of cousin primes under 1,000,000. The last one is 999,979 and 999,983. Thanks Python!

Comment: Sure took a darn long time tho... Python should run through the primes to a million at a darn fast speed.

Comment: Sorry I used brute force, which takes a lot longer. Would have used a more elegant (and faster) implementation if it mattered...but since this was just a one-time thing, I figured I'd make Python sweat it out for an hour...

Comment: Even with brute force it shouldn't be too bad as long as you only check odds for odd factors less than sqrt at minimum... Store positions in a list then easily find cousins in one pass.

Comment: @greenturtle3141: you could use [the standard congruence-based divisibility tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) to prune candidates. Do not assume it's brute-forcing. Consider you probably pick {4 odd numbers (excluding 5), 1 even (exlcuding 0)}. Then there are 4 x 4! = 96 possible primes (since prime cannot end in even number). The challenge is how many of those 96 candidates can we eliminate by cleverer things like congruences, instead of brute-forcing? The puzzle is which even number to pick, and why does it construct the most primes? (which of {2,4,6,8}?)

Comment: @smci Of course you can quickly eliminate roughly 1/3 of possible candidates by analysis of residues mod 3.  But in terms of time complexity I believe this is more or less negligible anyway.  Even so, this is still absolutely brute force, and I think we're both smart enough to correctly assume so.  Also, though my comments were from several years ago, I must emphasize that this was simply such a poor quality "puzzle" that to attempt to find any clever method like those tests would be akin to trying to find a gem from pure dirt.  So, there's really no point in this discussion.

Comment: @greenturtle3141: No I didn't agree it was poor or should have been closed; [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/83625/madam-i-m-adam-please-don-t-get-mad-you-will-no-longer-be-prime/83688#83688) is a similar prime-number-related digit puzzle. See my method in that answer. You could generalize that to here.

Comment: @smci Firstly, even if you can reduce the search space, it still reduces it to a brute force of some search space using a program.  Secondly, this was absolutely a poor puzzle in that there was virtually no creative thought involved in creating it.  One could easily ask something similar, i.e. "What is the smallest prime that uses each digit at least once?" or "Which 6-digit prime has the most number of primes that occur as a 'substring' of the prime?", etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have

> 39 prime numbers

from the digits

> {1, 3, 7, 8, 9}

They are:

> {13789, 13879, 17389, 17839, 18379, 18397, 18793, 18973, 19387, 37189, 38197, 38791, 38917, 38971, 71389, 71983, 73189, 73819, 78139, 78193, 79813, 81937, 81973, 83719, 83791, 87931, 89137, 89317, 89371, 91387, 91837, 91873, 93187, 93871, 97381, 97813, 98317, 98713, 98731}.